# How to Solve The Network Connection Was Lost Error in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsurlconnection, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I am using Xcode 6.1.1(6A2008a).I create an application with  have a Download class, and this is the Download class:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
@objc protocol ConnectionDelegate
{
func ConnectionDidFinish(nstate: NSString, nData:NSData, strstatuscode:NSInteger)
func ConnectionDidFail(nstate: NSString, nData:NSString)
}
@objc class MyClass : NSObject,NSURLConnectionDelegate
{
var connDelegate:ConnectionDelegate?
var responseFromServer:NSHTTPURLResponse?
var dataWebService: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
var activityView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
var strServiceName:NSString = ""

struct Static {
    static var instance:MyClass? = nil
    static var token:dispatch_once_t = 0
}
required override init() {

}

class func sharedConnectionWithDelegate(delegate:AnyObject)->MyClass
{

  Static.instance = self()
    Static.instance?.connDelegate=delegate as? ConnectionDelegate
    return Static.instance!

}

class func sharedConnection()->MyClass
{
   dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
        //          println("SQLiteDB - Dispatch once")
        Static.instance = self()
    }
    return Static.instance!

}
func GetStartUp(dic:NSDictionary,serviceName:NSString)
{
     self.strServiceName = serviceName
     self.getData(dic)

}
func getData(dataDict:NSDictionary)
{

   ShowNetworkActivityIndicator()
    if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork()
    {
       let request3=NSMutableURLRequest(URL:NSURL(string: MainUrl)!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.UseProtocolCachePolicy, timeoutInterval: 100000.0)


    request3.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var dict:NSDictionary? = dataDict
    if dict != nil
    {
        var error: NSError?
        var postData:NSData
        postData = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dataDict, options:nil, error: &error)!
        var postDataLengthString:NSString = NSString(format:"%d", postData.length)
        request3.setValue(postDataLengthString, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
        request3.HTTPBody=postData
    }
    request3.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
         var connection = NSURLConnection(request: request3, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)

    }
    else
    {
        HideNetworkActivityIndicator()
        connDelegate?.ConnectionDidFail("Internet connection is not available. Please try again later", nData: "Checking")
    }

}
//NSURLConnection delegate method
func connection(didReceiveResponse: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveResponse response: NSURLResponse!)
{
    println("get response")

    self.responseFromServer=response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
    dataWebService.length=0

    self.dataWebService = NSMutableData()
}
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didReceiveData data: NSData!)
{
    //Append incoming data
    println("get part of data")
    dataWebService.appendData(data)
}
func connectionDidFinishLoading(connection: NSURLConnection!)
{
    println("get Full response data")
    HideNetworkActivityIndicator()
    var  statuscode:Int?=0
    statuscode = self.responseFromServer?.statusCode

    connDelegate?.ConnectionDidFinish(self.strServiceName, nData:self.dataWebService, strstatuscode:statuscode!)
}
func connection(connection: NSURLConnection!, didFailWithError getError: NSError!)
{
    HideNetworkActivityIndicator()
    var error:NSError?
    println("error during responsestring: %@, \(getError?.description)")
    var  statuscode:Int?=0
    statuscode = self.responseFromServer?.statusCode
    if statuscode == 1
    {
        println("Request Failed Status Code 1")
        connDelegate?.ConnectionDidFail("Internet connection is not available. Please try again later", nData: "Checking")
    }
    else
    {
        println("Request Failed Status Code unknown")
        var responseString:NSString! = NSString(data: self.dataWebService, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            connDelegate?.ConnectionDidFail(getError.description, nData: responseString)
    }

}
```

i m getting This type of Error NSURLConnection failed with Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 “The network connection was lost.” in Swift iOS8.

Can any Give me detail how to Resolve or fix this Issue ?

Comment: Post your code in your question. Not in pastebin. the link will be available for some days only.

Comment: @AshishKakkad I Remove Code From PasteBin . i Edited in Question Please see it again my Question and reply Thanks in advance